# Can I make react-router cover only some urls and pass rest of the urls normally to the server?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, reactjs, routes, react-router

I have some routes defined for `react-router`. I wan't all other routes to be passed through the server normally as if there was no `react-router` in place.

If I just don't specify these routes I'm getting a warning when the page loads: "Warning: [react-router] Location "/Services" did not match any routes" but I could suffer this.

What I can't suffer is that when I'm on url covered by react-router and click Back button to go back to uncovered url then it doesn't work. I just see this error again and server is not asked again for uncovered url.

Any idea how to make site just partially covered by react router?

Comment: Are you using `react-router`'s `Link` for the link whose URLs you want to pass to the server? If yes, that might be the cause of your issue. Try using regular `a` tags for these links/URLs and it should work normally. If you post some code it would be really helpful.

Comment: @IoannisTziligkakis  I'm using regular `a` tags and the behavior I'm observing is nothing erroneous. My case is just not covered by default. By default react-router assumes it's supposed to cover all routes for the site. I just need it for slightly different use case where just some url-s are routed by `react-router` and others are routed on server side.

Comment: Could you post some code or your routes' configuration? It might have to do with routers overlapping between the client and the server, e.g. if you "catch" the route early on at the server and render a view, does it behave in the same way?

Comment: @IoannisTziligkakis I figured out how to do it. Basically you can't just render the router. You need to split router into matching and rendering and react to `browserHistory` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is manually use `react-router` as you would have on server-side.

```
# this is CoffeScript (cjsx)

window.router =
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route name="ServiceNotes" path="ServiceNotes/:location_id" component="ServiceNote" />
  </Router>

$(document).ready ->
  routes = createRoutes window.router.props.children

  initialLoad = true
  browserHistory.listen (location) ->
    match { routes, location: location.pathname }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) ->
      if !error && renderProps
        render <RouterContext {...renderProps} />, document.getElementById('page-container')
      else
        console.log "Server side navigation"
        if !initialLoad
          window.location.reload()
    initialLoad = false
```

1. Listen to history.
2. Match routes.
3. If routes match, render  as you would on server side.
4. If no routes match, on initial history event do nothing (we just came here) but on subsequent events reload current url from server (history prevented call to server after clicking back button or link on the page but we need it to go through because it's unmatched route so we do it manually).